# JSDOM - nodejs makes clean exit, doesn't load

Tags: node.js, express, phaser-framework, jsdom

I am following a tutorial on this site:
https://phasertutorials.com/creating-a-simple-multiplayer-game-in-phaser-3-with-an-authoritative-server-part-1/

I am trying to get the last step to work.

I tried this initially with my own code as I am begining to understand using node and express. I got the same error, so I did a clean start and followed the guide exactly as I thought I had made a mistake and couldn't find it. But now I think there is an issue in this function, I don't know of.

Everything works fine until I reach the last step- including this function:

```
function setupAuthoritativePhaser() {
  JSDOM.fromFile(path.join(__dirname, 'authoritative_server/index.html'), {
    // To run the scripts in the html file
    runScripts: "dangerously",
    // Also load supported external resources
    resources: "usable",
    // So requestAnimatinFrame events fire
    pretendToBeVisual: true
  }).then((dom) => {
    dom.window.gameLoaded = () => {
      server.listen(8081, function () {
        console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().port}`);
      });
    };
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
};
```

my nodemon makes a clean exit and waits for changes before restarting.

any ideas?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer. Apparently I am a fool, I removed the call of this function...

```
setupAuthoritativePhaser();
```

However, I am not getting the correct phaser tag  in the console log, it should say Phaser .... (Headless | HTML5 Audio) but it still says  Phaser v3.15.1 (WebGL | Web Audio), though in my node it says the correct phrase...

Comment: Hi @Magnus, I'm facing issues running Phaser in Headless mode too (using the same tutorial). I was wondering if you had any luck extending the tutorial to a real Phaser game, and if you'd faced further issues with the Headless mode?

Answer (score 0):

you need remove old code in server/index.js

```
server.listen(8081, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

and use

```
 dom.window.gameLoaded = () => {
      server.listen(8081, function () {
        console.log(`Listening on the ${server.address().port}`);
      });
 };
```

finaly server/index.js look like

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);

const path = require('path');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
// server.listen(8081, function () {
//   console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().port}`);
// });

function setupAuthoritativePhaser() {
  console.log(__dirname)
  JSDOM.fromFile(path.join(__dirname, '/authoritative_server/index.html'), {
    // To run the scripts in the html file
    runScripts: "dangerously",
    // Also load supported external resources
    resources: "usable",
    // So requestAnimatinFrame events fire
    pretendToBeVisual: true
  }).then((dom) => {
    dom.window.gameLoaded = () => {
      server.listen(8081, function () {
        console.log(`Listening on the ${server.address().port}`);
      });
    };
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
setupAuthoritativePhaser();
```